# how send artifact from azure devops to onedrive sharepoint folder

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, onedrive

I use Azure DevOps in order to make continuous integration (CI). I would like to push the binaries (artifacts) to a one drive sharepoint folder whose url is like this : https://foo.sharepoint.com/personal/bar/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx .

Thank you very much for your help !

I make some research and i attempt to do it with microsoft graph. But i don't understand how to make url....

I see also that many of customers like me want to do this : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/onedrive-support-for-devops-pipeline-release/548731.

I saw that it is possible to do this with a powershell script. But i don't know at all how to manage all this mess !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could follow this document for [Continuous Integration and Continuous deployment using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/implement-ci-cd-with-azure-devops)

After you create the artifacts, you could follow the steps below to publish it to share point in a `Release Pipeline`.

1.Adding a stage.

2.**Install the Node.JS tool** in your stage with node.js installer with the version 10.x.

`If your project is based on SharePoint Framework version 1.7.1 or earlier, use version 8.X.`

[image]

**3.Installing the CLI for Microsoft 365.**

Add a `npm` task, select a `Custom command` and type `install -g @pnp/cli-microsoft365` in the `Command and Arguments` field. Learn more about the CLI for Microsoft 365

[image]

**4.Connecting to SharePoint Online**

Before using the App Catalog in your deployment environment, you first need to authenticate against the App Catalog of your tenant. To do so, add a Command Line task and paste in the following command into the script field m365 login -t password -u $(username) -p $(password).

[image]

**note**

If you are using CLI for Microsoft 365 to connect to your tenant for the first time, you need to perform an **interactive logon** with the account first. This is required to grant access to PnP Office 365 Management Shell application which is used by CLI for Microsoft 365 to access your tenant on the account's behalf. Your task will otherwise fail to logon non-interactively. Details available on CLI for Microsoft 365 User Guide.

**5.Adding the Solution Package to the App Catalog**

Upload the solution package to your App Catalog by adding another Command Line task and pasting the following command line in the `Script` field `m365 spo app add -p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SpFxDevOps/drop/SharePoint/solution/sp-fx-devops.sppkg --overwrite`

The path of the package depends on your solution name (see your project configuration) as well as the Source Alias you defined earlier, make sure they match.

**Note**

You can upload a solution to a site collection app catalog by adding `--appCatalogUrl https://$(tenant).sharepoint.com/$(catalogsite) --scope sitecollection`

[image]

**6.Deploying the Application**

The final step in the setup is to deploy the application to the App Catalog to make it available to all site collections within the tenant as its latest version. Add another `Command Line` task and paste the following command line in the `Script` field `m365 spo app deploy --name sp-fx-devops.sppkg`

**Note**

You can deploy a solution from a site collection app catalog by adding `--appCatalogUrl https://$(tenant).sharepoint.com/$(catalogsite) --scope sitecollection`

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your proposal ! i don't much time now, i will test this solution maybe next week